# Is it possible to point sub-directory to another AWS Instance?

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

I have instance AWS1 with site at `/var/www/html` with instance IP pointing to `example.com`

Now I have another AWS2 instance with content at `/var/www/blog` and I want its content to be shown when users open `example.com/blog`

Is it possible to do it at DNS and at Apace virtual host level as moving data from one instance to another with the database is really time-consuming.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can achieve this using [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html). For example:

```
ProxyPass /blog/ http://aws2.instance/blog/
```